# На django на работает robots.txt

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, robots.txt

В url.py прописал

```
path("robots.txt", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt", content_type="text/plain"),
```

но по пути

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/robots.txt
```

страница не доступна. Но если поставить слеш в адресе, то страница есть

```
path("robots.txt/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt", content_type="text/plain"),
```

Но так поисковики не видят адрес домен/robots.txt

Яндекс проверка пишет, что адрес отвечает переадресацией. Оно то и правильно, ведь адрес у меня https://домен/robots.txt/, а должен быть https://домен/robots.txt
Кто знает, как сделать чтобы robots.txt начал работать без слеша в конце?

Comment: Почему бы не отдавать этот статичный файл с помощью nginx?

Comment: Прямо сейчас скопировал ваш код и проверил — у меня `path("robots.txt",` замечательно работает (только забытую скобочку закрыть надо). Если у вас не работает, максимально подробно опишите симптомы неработоспособности

Comment: И почистьте кэш своего браузера, возможно в нём просто закэшировалось перенаправление

Comment: @andreymal
тоже попробовал скопировать в другой проект, там у меня тоже работает. Но почему не работает на текущем проекте, совсем нет никаких догадок.

Comment: @KorsarD что значит «не работает»? Вы так и не рассказали, что у вас происходит вместо работы

Comment: Снес venv и заново переустановил все окружение, заработало